# How to use pyfakefs, pytest to test a function using `multiprocessing.Queue` via a `Manager`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pytest, pyfakefs

I am trying to test a code that uses `multiprocessing.Queue`. I tried using the `additional_skip_names`, calling `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` and `multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver')`, but nothing seems to work.

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import pytest
import multiprocessing
from pyfakefs.fake_filesystem_unittest import Patcher

def f():
    q = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    q.put(1)
    return q.get()


@pytest.fixture
def fs():
     with Patcher(additional_skip_names=['multiprocessing.connection']) as patcher:
         yield patcher.fs


def test_f1(fs):
    assert f() == 1

def test_f2():
    assert f() == 1
```

resulting in

```bash
$ pytest -q test.py 
FF                                                                                                        [100%]
=================================================== FAILURES ====================================================
____________________________________________________ test_f1 ____________________________________________________

fs = <pyfakefs.fake_filesystem.FakeFilesystem object at 0x7f12acbeadd0>

    def test_f1(fs):
>       assert f() == 1

/tmp/test.py:18: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/tmp/test.py:6: in f
    q = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py:57: in Manager
    m.start()
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py:566: in start
    self._address = reader.recv()
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py:250: in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py:414: in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <multiprocessing.connection.Connection object at 0x7f12acc40670>, size = 4
read = <bound method FakeOsModule.read of <pyfakefs.fake_filesystem.FakeOsModule object at 0x7f12acbeb190>>

    def _recv(self, size, read=_read):
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        handle = self._handle
        remaining = size
        while remaining > 0:
            chunk = read(handle, remaining)
            n = len(chunk)
            if n == 0:
                if remaining == size:
>                   raise EOFError
E                   EOFError

/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py:383: EOFError
--------------------------------------------- Captured stderr call ----------------------------------------------
Process SyncManager-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 591, in _run_server
    server = cls._Server(registry, address, authkey, serializer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.listener = Listener(address=address, backlog=16)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 448, in __init__
    self._listener = SocketListener(address, family, backlog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 591, in __init__
    self._socket.bind(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
____________________________________________________ test_f2 ____________________________________________________

    def test_f2():
>       assert f() == 1

test.py:21: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
test.py:6: in f
    q = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py:723: in temp
    token, exp = self._create(typeid, *args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py:606: in _create
    conn = self._Client(self._address, authkey=self._authkey)
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py:508: in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py:752: in answer_challenge
    message = connection.recv_bytes(256)         # reject large message
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py:216: in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py:414: in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py:379: in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
/home/xxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfakefs/fake_filesystem.py:5218: in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
/home/xxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfakefs/fake_filesystem.py:4241: in read
    file_handle = self.filesystem.get_open_file(fd)
/home/xxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfakefs/fake_filesystem.py:1578: in get_open_file
    self.raise_os_error(errno.EBADF, str(file_des))
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <pyfakefs.fake_filesystem.FakeFilesystem object at 0x7f12acbeadd0>, err_no = 9, filename = '12'
winerror = None

    def raise_os_error(
        self,
        err_no: int,
        filename: Optional[AnyString] = None,
        winerror: Optional[int] = None,
    ) -> NoReturn:
        """Raises OSError.
        The error message is constructed from the given error code and shall
        start with the error string issued in the real system.
        Note: this is not true under Windows if winerror is given - in this
        case a localized message specific to winerror will be shown in the
        real file system.
    
        Args:
            err_no: A numeric error code from the C variable errno.
            filename: The name of the affected file, if any.
            winerror: Windows only - the specific Windows error code.
        """
        message = os.strerror(err_no) + " in the fake filesystem"
        if winerror is not None and sys.platform == "win32" and self.is_windows_fs:
            raise OSError(err_no, message, filename, winerror)
>       raise OSError(err_no, message, filename)
E       OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor in the fake filesystem: '12'

/home/xxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfakefs/fake_filesystem.py:1149: OSError
============================================ short test summary info ============================================
FAILED test.py::test_f1 - EOFError
FAILED test.py::test_f2 - OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor in the fake filesystem: '12'
2 failed in 0.34s
Exception ignored in: <function _ConnectionBase.__del__ at 0x7f12acc80ca0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 132, in __del__
    self._close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 361, in _close
    _close(self._handle)
  File "/home/xxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfakefs/fake_filesystem.py", line 5218, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfakefs/fake_filesystem.py", line 4224, in close
    file_handle = self.filesystem.get_open_file(fd)
  File "/home/xxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfakefs/fake_filesystem.py", line 1577, in get_open_file
    return file_list[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
Exception ignored in: <function _ConnectionBase.__del__ at 0x7f12acc80ca0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 132, in __del__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 361, in _close
  File "/home/xxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfakefs/fake_filesystem.py", line 5218, in wrapped
  File "/home/xxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfakefs/fake_filesystem.py", line 4224, in close
  File "/home/xxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfakefs/fake_filesystem.py", line 1578, in get_open_file
  File "/home/xxx/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfakefs/fake_filesystem.py", line 1149, in raise_os_error
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor in the fake filesystem: '12'
```

Comment: This is [one of the limitations of pyfakefs](https://pytest-pyfakefs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#multiprocessing-build-in), so I'm afraid this won't work. I can have a closer look later at your concrete example, maybe there is still some workaround here.

Comment: I had a closer look, and the problem here is that files and pipes are opened using low-level OS-specific functions, which cannot be patched, and then the file descriptors are handed to (patched) Python file system functions. This won't work without a lot of specific (and os-specific) patching, and is currently not in the scope of `pyfakefs` (and this is not likely to change, as this would be a maintenance nightmare).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thank you for the comments. I will check other solutions then, I will leave the question here for a bit, and decide if I want to delete it in the future, if no answers or workarounds are given.